# mysql selecting a values with priority

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table location that has thousands of data

my sql query is

```
select * 
from location_table 
where country = "PH" 
and (province = "NCR" OR province = "") 
and (city = "makati" or city="") limit 10
```

location_table

```
ID | country | province | city
1  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
2  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
3  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
4  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
5  |   PH    |    NCR   | marikina
6  |   PH    |    NCR   | 
7  |   PH    |          | 
8  |   US    |          |
```

is this correct. is this going to be sure that my output will be like this

```
ID | country | province | city
1  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
2  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
3  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
4  |   PH    |    NCR   | makati
6  |   PH    |    NCR   | 
7  |   PH    |          |
```

i need to be sure that my query is accurate. do i need to improve my query? i need to prioritize the value of city and province. if it has a province. or else get the null value same with the city.

for example
city = makati
i need to prioritize getting all city that is "makati" value. what if on ID 3000 . there is a makati there. i need to get first all city with makati instead of city of null values. same with province.

Comment: What do you mean by prioritize? You don't have any grouping, so it will return all the rows with that province and city, or either of them blank. Priorizing would only apply if you need to choose one or the other within a group.

Comment: It will return the output you showed at the bottom, try it and see. If that's what you want, then it's correct.

Comment: but first. i need to get all city with value instead of city with null values.. for example

Comment: Are you talking about the order of the output?

Comment: yes @Barmar  prioritize getting first the given value before getting the null values.. i have updated my post.

Comment: "Prioritize"?  What happened to the last row?  You have a `limit 10` and yet the last row isn't in the output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  it's only an example sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` to put the non-empty values first:

```
select * 
from location_table 
where country = "PH" 
and (province = "NCR" OR province = "") 
and (city = "makati" or city="")
order by province = "", city = ""
```

`columnname = ""` will be `1` when the column is empty, otherwise it will be `0`.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96e8f6/1)

Comment: i need to get the value first sir.

Comment: That's what this does. `column = ""` is 0 when there's a value, it's 1 when it's empty. So the value will be first.

Comment: i need to order it by with value then the rest is no value

Comment: Look at my sqlfiddle demo, it does what you want!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from location_table 
where country = "PH" 
and (province = "NCR" OR province = "") 
and (city = "makati" or city="")
order by province, city
```

Order By will work on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For checking null always use 'is null' clause. Also find_in_set should help you